# Create sub lists by varying index in R

Tags: r, list, subset

I am trying to create sub-lists of the following form from another list without using a loop-
List - [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Result - [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

Please do not mind my lack of etiquette / R skills. I'm new to both Stackoverflow and R. Thank you.

Comment: The structure doesn't look like the one in R

Answer (score 2):

Compute the indexes of the input using `seq_along` and then apply a function to each index which gives the corresponding list component.  (In the question `v` actually equals `seq_along(v)` so if that were known to be the case then the solution could be simplified to just `lapply(v, seq_len)` .

```
v <- 1:5 # test input
lapply(seq_along(v), function(x) v[seq_len(x)])
```

giving:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1 2

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[4]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[5]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```